# How to camelCase a String in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm trying to get from:

```
'hello how are you today'
```

to

```
'helloHowAreYouToday'
```

And I thought `asCapitalizedPhrase asLegalSelector` would do the trick, but it doesn't.

What's the proper way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I think I should clarify my question; I already have a way to transform a string into a camelCase selector:

```
|aString aCamelCaseString|
aString := aString findTokens: $ .
aCamelCaseString := aString first.
aString allButFirst do: [:each | aCamelCaseString := aCamelCaseString , each capitalized].
```

I was just wondering whether Pharo has a standard system method to achieve the same :)

Comment: Have you considered writing your own method to do this? You essentially just need to tokenise, capitalise the initial letter of each token, and collect into a single string.

Comment: Yes, I do have an implementation to do this, but I was wondering whether Pharo does already have a standard way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which version of Pharo you're using, but in the stable 5.0,

```
'hello world this is a selector' asCamelCase asValidSelector
```

yields

```
helloWorldThisIsASelector
```

To get what I'm using run:

```
curl get.pharo.org/50+vm | bash
```

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
| tokens |
tokens := 'this is a selector' findTokens: Character space.
tokens allButFirst
    inject: tokens first
    into: [:selector :token | selector, token capitalized]
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an existing method doing this.

Here's an implementation that solves your problem:

```
input := 'hello how are you today'.
output := String streamContents: [ :stream |
    | capitalize |
    capitalize := false.
    input do: [ :char |
        char = Character space
            ifTrue: [ capitalize := true ]
            ifFalse: [
                stream nextPut: (capitalize
                    ifTrue: [ char asUppercase ]
                    ifFalse: [ char ]).
                capitalize := false ] ] ].
```

**Edit:** note, in comparison to Frank's solution this one is longer but it does not break for empty input and it does not create a new string instance *for each* step since it streams over the input, which is more efficient (in case you have large strings).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but Squeak has a useful implementation (String>>asCamelCase) which basically does this:

```
(String
    streamContents: [:stream | 'hello world' substrings
            do: [:sub | stream nextPutAll: sub capitalized]]) asLegalSelector
```